# Adding 360 VR photo viewer in flutter app

Tags: image, animation, flutter, 3d

Is there any library available like VrPanoramaView 
 in android for making 3d image view. IDK if the flutter animation is enough for the 3d rendering of images.

Answer (score 2):

I found https://github.com/innovationmauritiustelecom/video_player_360 but you can contribute and make it support 360 images

Answer (score 0):

Nothing here yet.

You could use https://pub.dev/packages/panorama for 360 Image View but It's not possible to implement it as a CardBoard o VirtualReality Experience.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this package useful in 3d rendering. I am answering my own question, so that someone can found this useful.
[three_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/three_dart)